# PHP rows inserting in reverse order to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stumped; I'm guessing this is something simple...?

I am inserting data gathered from PHPExcel (though this probably doesn't matter).  On my test box (Windows WAMP server), this works perfectly.  When I run in production on a linux server, the data is entering the database from bottom to top. My first line is a heading (Name, email, address, etc).  This ends up last in the SQL. Sure, I can reverse output, but I'd rather know what I'm doing wrong, especially as I'm not sure it's 100% predictable.

I have tried with the prep stmt inside the loop - makes no difference.

Any help?

```
// Prep ahead of loop to save cpu time
$insert_stmt = $dbc->prepare
("INSERT INTO contacts (id, name, dept, u1, u2) VALUES (0, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

for ($row = $chosenRow; $row < sizeof($temp) +1; $row++){
    // To allow dynamic # of cols, must always check to see if data is available
    $u1 = array_key_exists(1, $temp[$row])?$temp[$row][1]:"";
    $u2 = array_key_exists(2, $temp[$row])?$temp[$row][2]:"";


    $insert_stmt->bind_param('siss', $temp[$row][0], $importToDept,$u1,$u2);

    // PRINTING OF THIS PARAM ROW HERE SHOWS PROPER ORDER

    // Execute the prepared query.
    if (! $insert_stmt->execute() ) {
        doError();
        exit();
    }
}
```

Contacts creation table (but, looking at the database via PHPAdmin shows the rows are reversed in the DB, so likely not a problem with the creation):

```
$items = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE dept = $dept_id");

    echo "<table style='border-collapse:collapse; border:0px; margin-top:25px;'>";
    $row = 0;
    foreach ($items as $v){
        if ($limit > 0 && $row > $limit)
            break;
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($v as $key=>$col){
            if ($key == "id" || $key == "dept")
                continue;
            if ($row == 0)
                echo "<th>$col</th>";
            else 
                echo "<td>$col</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        $row++;
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Can we see the create statement for the `contacts` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, a bit of searching into the MYSQL manual pointed me in the right direction.  This type of insert & query is not something I have ever depended upon like this, so I didn't realize what I was doing wrong.

For anyone in future who might make this same mistake in assumption, here's the problem:

I assumed (correctly I believe), that the data goes IN to the DB, FIFO.  In other words, they are NOT entering the DB in reverse.  I was concentrating on the input, when i should have been thinking of how the query was pulling it out.  @Evan de la Cruz was right in asking about the create statement, and got me hunting in the right direction.

The issue is on the sort order of the *query*.  **SQL doesn't guarantee a sort order on the return.  It gives whatever is fastest / most efficient.**  Even in PHPMyadmin, which was screwing up my bug hunt.

For me, the answer is to simply sort on the id, which is an auto_increment field.

HTH.

Comment: Glad my comment helped, though it was sheer coincidence.  When I asked for the create statement for the table, I meant for the mysql table for example `create table contacts (dept int(10), foo varchar(10))`...  You sent the HTML table.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html